# Can I create dll in MONO for using inside Java Application

Tags: java, dll, mono, java-native-interface

We need to implement a DLL which will be run in Java Application, How we can achieve this without developing Java ? Because our main DLL developed with C++ so we will write a DLL that implements main DLL than we will use it in Java Application

Comment: A DLL written in MONO (which is for C#) written in C++ for use in Java? Are you sure that is all correct? I thought Mono was just for C#?

Comment: Maybe we have some missunderstanding points, but to be shortly our main dll developed with C++ now we need to be use Dll in Java , I thought mono can do that..

Comment: Mono is a project to bring Microsofts .net platform to Linux. To the best of my knowledge any system library/dll can be accessed from Java via JNI Java native interface. Though I have only ever tried with DLL written in C++

Comment: You need to be more specific. How does Mono come into the equation? Do you plan to write a .Net DLL? Do you want to run your "Java application" on the Mono .NET runtime (using something like IKVM)?

Comment: You do not need a "mono" (~= .net) wrapper for a c++ dll to use it in Java. You can access it directly using [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html). But _"How we can achieve this without developing Java ?"_ - **Not at all**. Even with a .net wrapper you'd have to "build a bridge" ...

Comment: @Fildor Yeah, and building/using that "bridge" would be a nightmare. We've done that using [jni4net](http://jni4net.com/). It wasn't fun at all.

Comment: @StefanZobel I didn't say it would be fun'n'games ... :D Maintenance is pure hell and lead to me being forced to cancel a vacation because I was the only one who halfway knew what the code was doing. Or at least what it was supposed to do ... never again.

Comment: JNI means "Java Native Interface". It requires a Java class method with the `native` keyword. Such method declarations can be written by you, generated for you (SWiG) or implemented in a bridging library (JNA/JNAerator, jni4net, JNIWrapper,jni4net, …).

Comment: If you are only developing this for one application, consider the Dependency Inversion Principle. Write a Java interface the application requires a service provider to implement. It should be natural, idiomatic Java.

Comment: Thank you for all answers f, inally I have an idea for what I have to do for such a case. Now we will focus on JNI to achieve this operation.